# how to put col-sm-1 to be in toggle navigation when it's in mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have col-sm-1, col-sm-9, col-sm-2 grid. When It's in mobile, I want my col-sm-1 to be in toggle navigation since it's just a sidebar. IS it possible to achieve this?

Comment: have a look at media-queries http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is hidden-* and visible-* classes which you can use to toggle the display of content in different viewports:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes